# MonoDevelop.AddinMaker - 'MonoDevelop.Core,5.10' is disabled

Tags: xamarin, mono, monodevelop, add-in, xamarin-studio

I am working on an MonoDevelop Addin (using [MonoDevelop.AddinMaker](https://github.com/mhutch/MonoDevelop.AddinMaker)) within Tamarin Studio and MonoDevelop and everything *was* fine, till I needed to access the GTK# Toolbox to fix some existing GUI panels (originally from the `CSharpBinding` GUIs).

The GTK# Widget that is referenced in those panels are in `MonoDevelop.Ide.dll`, so I added that to the GTK# ToolBox and the widgets show up. But the build generates invalid partial classes due to missing widget reference (`MonoDevelop.Ide`) and that reference is not available via the AddinMaker's Addin References system so I added a manual assembly reference to `MonoDevelop.Ide.dll`.

Now the debugging of the Addin fails with:

```
ERROR [2015-11-22 11:47:39Z]: Add-in error (MonoDevelop.Ide,5.10): Add-in could not be loaded: The required addin 'MonoDevelop.Core,5.10' is disabled.
Mono.Addins.MissingDependencyException: The required addin 'MonoDevelop.Core,5.10' is disabled.
   at Mono.Addins.AddinEngine.ResolveLoadDependencies (System.Collections.ArrayList addins, System.Collections.Stack depCheck, System.String id, Boolean optional) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/AddinEngine.cs:line 597
   at Mono.Addins.AddinEngine.ResolveLoadDependencies (System.Collections.ArrayList addins, System.Collections.Stack depCheck, System.String id, Boolean optional) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/AddinEngine.cs:line 612
ERROR [2015-11-22 11:47:39Z]: Add-in error (MonoDevelop.Core,5.10): Disabled add-ins can't be loaded.
Loaded assembly: /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/Mono.Addins.CecilReflector.dll [External]
Thread started:  #3
Unloaded assembly: /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/bin/Mono.Addins.CecilReflector.dll
Thread finished:  #3
System.InvalidOperationException: Extension node not found in path: /MonoDevelop/Core/WebCredentialProviders
   at Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects[T] (System.String path, Boolean reuseCachedInstance) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionContext.cs:line 636
   at Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects[T] (System.String path) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionContext.cs:line 607
   at Mono.Addins.AddinManager.GetExtensionObjects[T] (System.String path) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/AddinManager.cs:line 630
   at MonoDevelop.Core.WebRequestHelper.Initialize () in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core/WebRequestHelper.cs:line 49
   at MonoDevelop.Core.Runtime.Initialize (Boolean updateAddinRegistry) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Core/MonoDevelop.Core/Runtime.cs:line 118
Starting Xamarin Studio
FATAL ERROR [2015-11-22 11:47:42Z]: Xamarin Studio failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run Xamarin Studio (for example gtk-sharp)may not be properly installed in the GAC.
System.InvalidOperationException: Extension node not found in path: /MonoDevelop/Core/PlatformService
   at Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects (System.String path, System.Type arrayElementType, Boolean reuseCachedInstance) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionContext.cs:line 669
   at Mono.Addins.ExtensionContext.GetExtensionObjects (System.String path) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/ExtensionContext.cs:line 534
   at Mono.Addins.AddinManager.GetExtensionObjects (System.String path) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/external/mono-addins/Mono.Addins/Mono.Addins/AddinManager.cs:line 554
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.DesktopService.Initialize () in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/DesktopService.cs:line 56
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (MonoDevelop.Ide.MonoDevelopOptions options) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:line 175
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Main (System.String[] args, MonoDevelop.Ide.Extensions.IdeCustomizer customizer) in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2103/7c46a0b7/source/monodevelop/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide/IdeStartup.cs:line 652
```

I removed the assembly reference, removed the GTK Toolbox MonoDevelop components/widget, etc.. but the problem persists.

MonoDevelop and Xamarin Studio run fine by themselves, so how do I **re-enable(?)** the `MonoDevelop.Core` addin in the AddinMaker Project?

Comment: I would try deleting the addin-db-002 directory (might be called something different) which is inside the directory of your addin's bin/Debug directory.

Comment: @MattWard, THANK YOU!, that was it (a corrupt list of `*.maddin` within the sub-dir of `addin-data/1`), Doesn't fix the root-cause, but at least now I can debug the AddinMaker to determine what is causing it. I owe you a beer or six.... ;-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I would try deleting the addin-db-002 directory (might be called
>   something different) which is inside the directory of your addin's
>   bin/Debug directory. – Matt Ward

That was actually the problem, the `addin-db-002` does not cleaned up on a `Clean All`, nor does it get a complete update on a `Build All`.

So once you have a 'corrupt' list of addin's within the sub-dir of `./addin-data/1` they do not get re-created unless you manually delete the `addin-db-002`.